# combinate input-fields for Livevalidation

Tags: javascript, livevalidation

i check some Input Fields with Livevalidation if they are not empty.
For this i am using the following code:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var street = new LiveValidation('street');
            var streetnumber = new LiveValidation('streetnumber');
            street.add( Validate.Presence );
            streetnumber.add( Validate.Presence );
        </script>
```

The both input-Filds are inline.
But the message will be always directly displayd behind the input-Field.
Now, the Message from the first input-Field will Reposition the second Field.

I am looking for the best way to combinate the Validation from 2 Fields and shown only one Message.

here you can see the actual result: http://jsfiddle.net/Vme7C/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Vme7C/1/

```
var street = new LiveValidation('street',{
    onValid:showmessage(true),onInvalid:showmessage(false)
});
var streetnumber = new LiveValidation('streetnumber',{
    onValid:showmessage(true),onInvalid:showmessage(false)
});

var streetvalid=false,streetnumbervalid=false,
    ls=document.getElementById('msgli');
function showmessage(val){
    return function(){
        if(this.element.id=="street")
            streetvalid=val;
        else
            streetnumbervalid=val;
        if(streetvalid && streetnumbervalid){
            ls.innerHTML="All fields are valid";
            return;
        }
        if(!streetvalid && !streetnumbervalid){
            ls.innerHTML="No field is valid";
            return;
        }
        ls.innerHTML=(!streetvalid?"Street":"Street number")
            +" field is invalid";
        return;
    }
}

street.add(Validate.Presence);
streetnumber.add(Validate.Presence);
```

Comment: Thx a lot - this modification works perfect!
But i don´t need it any more - now i use the Livevalidation only to check the inputvalues (is it valide or invalide) and animate the Fields with CSS3 UI Module like http://alistapart.com/d/forward-thinking-form-validation/index.html

Comment: @user2401273 then you may check my answer as Correct ;)